# Php function not define

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, class, function

I have a function with a default value of nothing, example:

```
function output_message($message="") {
  if (!empty($message)) { 
    return "<p class=\"message\">{$message}</p>";
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

I then am echoing the message on my log in form.  If there are errors it will display a message but if there are no errors it should just do nothing.  When my page loads it says my function is not defined.  Below is my html page.

```
<?php
require_once("../../includes/functions.php");
require_once("../../includes/session.php");
require_once("../../includes/database.php");
require_once("../../includes/user.php");

if($session->is_logged_in()) {
  redirect_to("index.php");
}

// Remember to give your form's submit tag a name="submit" attribute!
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.

  $username = trim($_POST['username']);
  $password = trim($_POST['password']);

  // Check database to see if username/password exist.
  $found_user = User::authenticate($username, $password);

  if ($found_user) {
    $session->login($found_user);
    redirect_to("index.php");
  } else {
    // username/password combo was not found in the database
    $message = "Username/password combination incorrect.";
  }

} else { // Form has not been submitted.
  $username = "";
  $password = "";
}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link href="../stylesheets/main.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Photo Gallery</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <h2>Staff Login</h2>
        <?php echo output_message($message); ?>

        <form action="login.php" method="post">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Username:</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo htmlentities($username); ?>" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Password:</td>
              <td>
                <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo htmlentities($password); ?>" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Copyright <?php echo date("Y", time()); ?>, Kevin Skoglund</div>
  </body>
</html>
<?php if(isset($database)) { $database->close_connection(); } ?>
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error because in my function i am setting the default value of $message in the function. output_message($message="").

Can someone look at my code and tell me why it is telling me my function is not defined. Thanks.

Comment: Missing a closing `?>` before `<html>`? Where is the `output_message()` function defined? Also, I recommend you enable decent error reporting for development. Place this at the top of your script; `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: You also might want to initialize your `$message` variable to avoid warnings of undefined variables (not related to undefined functions...).

Comment: @phil it is in the function file which is in my includes folder which is included at the top of the doc.

Comment: @Jeroen i thought i was defining it when i built the function as output_message($message="") i set the default value.  When i define $message = "" at the top of the doc outside of the function things work fine - so now my question is why isn't my default value working in the function.  I set default value by output_message($message="").

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, it seems that it is not the function that is not defined, but the variable.

The problem is not with the function itself, there your variable `$message` is set to an empty string if no variable is supplied to the function.

The problem is with your function call:

```
<?php echo output_message($message); ?>
```

Here you are calling your function with a variable, also called `$message`, but completely unrelated to the variable `$message` in your function. This global variable does not exist and that is why php is giving you a warning.

The way you defined your function, means that you can call it like:

```
<?php echo output_message(); ?>
```

without any problems; if no variable is supplied, the `$message` variable in the function is set to an empty string.

However, using:

```
<?php echo output_message($any_variable_name); ?>
```

will generate a warning when `$any_variable_name` is not defined in the scope you are in (in this case the global scope).

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know where are you using the output_message but my first guess is that those functions "redirect_to" may be the problem.

Those functions most of the time do something like this:

```
   header( 'Location: http://some_where_on.yourweb' );
```

Check that you have made the right includes in the .php file where you are using the output_message function.

Also, i would recommend to follow the advises Phil and jeroen told as comments:

- missing ?> before  tag
- add init_set("display_errors","On"); error_reporting(E_ALL)
- initialize variables like $message to avoid warnings and side effects
- Try not to mix rendering with logic (this one is mine)